# Как получить контекст в адаптере

Tags: android, context

Cделал `onClick()` в `onBindViewHolder()`, но есть небольшая проблема. Выходит NullPointerExeption, но логирование при этом работает нормально, все позиции выдает, спотыкается на диалоге, думаю это возможно из за `context`, я его задал так:

```
 public Context context;
```

Задал так, потому что ни `getContext()`, ни что то иное не работает.

Cам `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "position = " + holder.getAdapterPosition());

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("tittle")
                        .setMessage("hi")

                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNegativeButton("закрыть",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

P.S.    Я его просто указал в основание класса , как написал выше (так предложила Android Studio). Почти уверен, что из-за этого `null`, но я не знаю как еще получить `Context`. Раньше всегда спасало `getContext()`, `getActivity()` в таких случаях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо было использовать holder и itemView. `holder.itemView.getContext()`

Answer (score 7):

Если вы просто написали:

```
public Context context;
```

и расчитываете, что таким образом вы получили контекст, то это не так. Этой строкой вы просто создали ссылку с именем `context` для хранения объекта класса `Context`. Сам объект при этом отсутствует (не получен), потому что контекст, это не просто какое то слово, а объект, содержащий определенные данные и чтобы его использовать, эти данные предварительно должны быть получены из классов, которые содержат эту информацию.

Решить проблему можно двумя способами:

1. Передать контекст из активити или фрагмента (которые имеет информацию о контексте) через конструктор адаптера.
2. Получить контекст из какого-либо `View` в адаптере

В случае диалога рекомендуется использовать контекст активти, так как в контексте `View` может быть другая информация, например, о используемой теме и др.

PS: Методы `getContext()` и `getActivity()` это методы класса `Activity` и `Fragment`. Адаптер не наследуется от этих классов и эти методы в нем отсутствуют. Так же адаптер не является наследником никаких классов, которые имеют контекст и внутри себя для прямого доступа его не имеет.

PPS: делать поля класса, которые используются только внутри класса публичными решительно не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 0):

В адаптере я получил context так:

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    final TextView probegView;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        probegView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.probeg_list);
        Setting._set_size(view.getContext(), 16, -1, probegView);
        probegView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```